# Laravel 5.2 eloquent eager loading select columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building an API interface for one of my clients eCommerce website and I'm stuck.

**Version** Laravel 5.2

**Problem:**
Can't select the specific column from the eagerly loaded models.

```
    Route::get('/product/{id}', function($id){
    return \App\Models\Product::where('id',$id)->with(
        [
            'images',
            'reviews',
            'relatedProducts' => function($query){
                $query->with('images');
            }
        ])->first(['id', 'name', 'price', 'description']); // this one is working
   });
```

What i tried:

```
'relatedProducts:id,title,description' => function($query){
                $query->with('images'); 
                }
```

Error:

[image]

```
'relatedProducts' => function($query){
                $query->with('images');
                $query->select(['id','title','description']);
            }
```

Note: relatedProducts comes from the same table as products. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//...
return \App\Models\Product::where('id',$id)->with(
        [
            'images',
            'reviews',
            'relatedProducts' => function ($q) {             
               $q->select('id','title','description');
            },
            'relatedProducts.images' 
        ])->first(['id', 'name', 'price', 'description']);

//...
```